# How to remove the the previous instance created in React useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, alan

This is my useEffect().I am making a website using React and alan voice recognition.
What this useEffect() does is when someone enters the country it creates an alanBtn which is basically a button.Now the problem is that when the user selects another country the previous button stays on the page and on top of it a new button is made.
What I want to do is whenever a user selects a different country it destroys the previous button instance and then creates new one.

```
useEffect(() => {
    alanbtn({
      key: alanKey,
      onCommand: ({ command, articles, number }) => {
        if (command === "newHeadlines") {
          setNewsArticles(articles);
          setActiveArticle(-1);
        } else if (command === "highlight") {
          setActiveArticle((prevValue) => prevValue + 1);
        } else if (command === "open") {
          const parseNumber =
            number.length > 2
              ? wordsToNumbers(number, { fuzzy: true })
              : number;

          const article = articles[parseNumber - 1];
          if (parseNumber > 20) {
            alanbtn().playText("Please try that again");
          } else if (article) {
            window.open(article.url, "_blank");
            alanbtn().playText("Opening...");
          }
        }
      },
    }).setVisualState({ answer: country });
  }, [country]);
```

The country is passed as prop to this component.

Comment: Effects can return a cleanup function: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup

Comment: Well I know this method but it is not deleting the alan button instance. I don't know why

Comment: Hmm, I haven't used this "alan" before, but it sounds like perhaps it's creating a new instance each time it's called. Have you tried assigning it to the components state and accessing it from there? Their documentation seems to have the class-based [equivalent of this](https://github.com/alan-ai/alan-sdk-web/blob/master/examples/alan-example-integration-react/src/App.js).

Comment: Well this problem can also be solved if my page reload everytme it is rendered.Now I don't know how to reload a page when rendered. I used browser-router to render different components.

Comment: you need to use an own component only for the button, specify the rootEl with a useRef. Then the whole component including the button can be removed and added again. See the example: [React App with Alan](https://github.com/alan-ai/alan-sdk-web/blob/master/examples/alan-example-integration-react/src/App.js)